# RVM install using wrong URL

Tags: rvm

I'm trying to install ruby-1.9.3-p194 using RVM and it is failing. It looks like the reason is that it is trying to download the source from bad urls. The output I get is:

```
% rvm install ruby-1.9.3-p194
Searching for binary rubies, this might take some time.
No binary rubies available for: osx/10.10/x86_64/ruby-1.9.3-p194.
Continuing with compilation. Please read 'rvm help mount' to get more information on binary rubies.
Checking requirements for osx.
Certificates in '/usr/local/etc/openssl/cert.pem' are already up to date.
Requirements installation successful.
Installing Ruby from source to: /Users/robertlooby/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194, this may take a while depending on your cpu(s)...
ruby-1.9.3-p194 - #downloading ruby-1.9.3-p194, this may take a while depending on your connection...
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0curl: (22) The requested URL returned error: 404 Not Found
The requested url does not exist(22): 'http://cache.ruby-lang.org/pub/ruby/./ruby-1.9.3-p194.tar.bz2'
Checking fallback: http://ftp.ruby-lang.org/pub/ruby/./ruby-1.9.3-p194.tar.bz2
Checking fallback: http://www.mirrorservice.org/sites/ftp.ruby-lang.org/pub/ruby/./ruby-1.9.3-p194.tar.bz2
No fallback URL could be found, try increasing timeout with:

    echo "export rvm_max_time_flag=20" >> ~/.rvmrc

There has been an error fetching the ruby interpreter. Halting the installation.
```

In each of the requested URLs where it has `/./` it should have `/1.9/`. Any idea how to fix this or what is causing it?

I am using version 1.26.4 of RVM

Comment: I'm seeing the same path error trying to download the latest ruby-2.0.0p647. p645 installed correctly. Really weird.

Comment: also having this issues trying to install 2.3.2